# Power BI REST API - Remove User Access Not Working

Tags: python, powerbi

I want to revoke user access to a dataset using REST APIs. According to the documentation, I can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/put-dataset-user-in-group) API endpoint with `datasetUserAccessRight: None` to remove all the dataset permissions of the specified user.

Upon using this API endpoint, I get a 200 successful response, but the user still has access to the dataset. I also tried refreshing the user permissions as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/users/refresh-user-permissions).

Is there a bug in the API itself or is my request wrong?

```py
def revoke_access(access_token, user, group_id, dataset_id):
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
    }

    api_url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/datasets/{dataset_id}/users'

    share_details = {
        "identifier": user,
        "principalType": "User",
        "datasetUserAccessRight": "None"
    }

    response = requests.put(api_url, headers=headers,
                            data=json.dumps(share_details))
```